# In mono, when i run my console app, how can I save the stdout to a file?

Tags: c#, console, mono

When I run my (precompiled) c# program in mono - how do I get the output to save into a file.

The process seems to open a new console window - so simple > and | dont work

For what it's worth, the program is an IRC bot (benign) and i'm trying to make it work on linux (ubuntu 14.04) with mono.